# Can't validate password_hash generated in console in front-end

Tags: yii2, console-application, yii2-advanced-app, password-hash

I do `generatePasswordHash` from console to create a user. And when user is created, I can't login. I try to `validatePassword` but it always returns false. But when I do the same `generatePasswordHash` in front-end part it returns true. 
Is there any difference between validation or generating hash from console and front-end?

Comment: There should be the same process for both. It must be something else you are doing. It would help if you paste the code for creating user in console app.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same PHP version in console and web app?

Comment: It can be different even for same PHP version, if `mods_available` are different for cli and web

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was wrong. I was parsing csv file and used wrong string to create password. Not actually wrong, the password string I used was like this: `"password"\n
`, so in the end there was even new line...

Answer (score 0):

What I finally understood is that password hash generated in console **can** be validated in frontend. That was only my mistake. Hope this helps to someone.)